# Retrieving objects from JSON using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json

I need to send some data stored in IndexedDB to server for some back-end manipulation. The needed data is fetched to a variable `payLoad` in javascript using `JSON.stringify()`.

```
 payLoad = "[{"synch":0,"id":-1,"name":"Tester","email":"test@example.com","created":"2014-08-20T07:56:44.201Z"}]";
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "process.php",
                data: payLoad,      // NOTE CHANGE HERE
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                },
                error: function(msg) {
                alert('error');
                }

            });
```

Can I parse this JSON data to a PHP class?

Comment: [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode)

Comment: Can I know the code please? Additionally, how can I obtain this JSON String in PHP using $_POST[]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way, you're just sending JSON raw in the body. Try this:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

If, on the other hand, you send data with this:

```
data: { data: payLoad },
```

Then you can simply do

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
```

Comment: The key point of the answer lies in the first code snippet in this answer.